# How can I extend a CSS class with additional rules?

Tags: css, gwt

I want to create different button styles, which should only differ in the color. So I'd thought I make a base CSS class for the button, and inherit them and just override the color (at least that would be my approach from the Java perspective...).

```
.myButton {
   padding:...
   width:...
   background: white;
}

.myButton-ok {
  background: green;
}

.myButton-warn {
 background: orange;
}
```

But how can I make these classes extend the `.myButton` class, so that I only have to apply eg `.myButton-ok` and all other base button styles are maintained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional class to the button to take effect. Something like this-

```
.myButton {
padding:...
width:...
background: white;
}

.red {
background: red;
}

.blue {
background: blue;
}

<button Class="myButton">Button</button>  // basic button
<button Class="myButton red">Button</button>  // with red BG
<button Class="myButton blue">Button</button>  // with blue BG
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS doesn't work like that. It doesn't use inheritance *per se*... it uses a cascade based on the specificity of the selector to override properties. The only way to do that would be with pre-processor like LESS or SASS where you could extend them.

With raw CSS I would assign two classes the button with the default styles and then the button with the specific styles:

```
<a class="myButton myButton-ok"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Css you cannot do like that.

However, in these type of situations, we can achieve same by segregating common properties and specific properties as below:

```
 .myButton, myButton-ok, myButton-warn {
   padding:...
   width:...;
   /*Other common properties, except specific ones like "background"*/
}

.myButton-ok {
  background: green;
}

.myButton-warn {
 background: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS the "strength" order is like this:

inline style > class > id.

So you could define a common class button:

```
.myButton {
padding:...
width:..};
```

and for your OK button you define an inline style (in html):

```
style="background:green"
```

alternatively, you can always define a specific id style for each button, but for just changing color i think it is overkilled:

```
#myButton-ok{ background: green};
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS has no class or inheritance concept in the programming sense. It has just class selectors, which let you specify properties for elements with a specific `class` attribute (an HTML thing), and it has inheritance in a completely different sense: under certain conditions, an element inherits property values from its parent in the document tree (and this has nothing to do with classes).

Thus, we need to think differently. In your example case, you could use e.g.

```
.myButton {
   padding:...
   width:...
   background: white;
}

.ok {
   background: green;
}

.warn {
   background: orange;
}
```

and markup like `<button class="button warn">`. This would mean that the element belongs to two classes and has declarations for both of them applied. Here it becomes relevant that other things being equal, if two declarations for the same property apply to an element, the latter declaration (i.e., the one appearing later in style sheets) wins.